# Tkinter: using custom events with a menu on Windows

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, tcl

Using Python 3.9.4

In the interest of loose coupling, I'm trying to implement a main menu in Tkinter that generates custom events rather than directly calling a callback function.  The example script shows the basic approach:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
label = tk.Label(text='Test')
label.grid()
menu = tk.Menu(root)

root.configure(menu=menu)

submenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(menu=submenu, label='Change Text')
submenu.add_command(
    label='Foo',
    command=lambda: menu.event_generate('<<Foo>>')
)
submenu.add_command(
    label='Bar',
    command=lambda: menu.event_generate('<<Bar>>')
)

def setfoo(*_):
    label.configure(text='Foo')

def setbar(*_):
    label.configure(text='Bar')

menu.bind('<<Foo>>', setfoo)
menu.bind('<<Bar>>', setbar)

root.mainloop()
```

This approach works in Linux, but on Windows the bindings do not work.  They appear to be bound to the event, but nothing happens when the menu item is selected.

I am assuming this has to do with the difference between menu implementations on Windows and Linux, but is there a correct way to do this, or a workaround?

EDIT:  To help everyone understand better why I'm wanting to do certain things, here is an object-oriented version that more closely aligns with how I'm using Tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainMenu(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        submenu = tk.Menu(self)
        submenu.add_command(
            label="foo",
            command=lambda: self.event_generate('<<Foo>>')
        )
        submenu.add_command(
            label="bar",
            command=lambda: self.event_generate('<<Bar>>')
        )
        self.add_cascade(menu=submenu, label='Test')


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        menu = MainMenu(self)
        self.configure(menu=menu)

        menu.bind('<<Foo>>', print)
        menu.bind('<<Bar>>', print)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Note that the `MainMenu` class would be defined in a separate file, so the `app` global is not available to it.  I could use `MainMenu.master` to get the root window in this case, but that breaks loose coupling as it assumes the root window is the parent of this class.  That assumption could break (say the mainwindow gets put in a hamburger menu, or added to another `TopLevel` that isn't the main app).

Comment: To simplify the code you can just have `menu.bind("<<Foo>>", print)` and `menu.event_generate("<<Foo>>")`. The print statement is never called. This is an interesting problem.

Comment: as interesting as it is, if You use `root.event_generate()` and then `root.bind()` it works, also using `label.event_generate()` and then `label.bind()` works, so it could be something to do with `Menu` (maybe, I don't know)

Comment: Binding to `root` may have to be the workaround, but that sort of kills the idea of loose coupling.  I suppose that's not too bad since a root window must exist somewhere in the application.

Comment: Typically you would generate the events on some other widgets, such as the root window or the window that has focus. Generating them on a menu seems like an odd choice. Is there a specific reason you're choosing to generate them on the menu?

Comment: @BryanOakley In the actual application, I'm doing this object-oriented.  The Menu is its own class, and in trying to be loosely-coupled, I'm trying to minimize references to things outside the class.  Keeping in mind the class itself may be defined in a separate file, there may be no reference to `root` available, and it would certainly be inappropriate to bind to items outside root.  Since the user is interacting with the menu, it makes sense to me that the menu would be the one generating these events, and the main application is listening to the menu for them (via the `bind`).

Comment: The menu will have a reference to a parent, and from the parent you can get the root window, FWIW.

Comment: @BryanOakley  I added some code to better illustrate the OOP situation.  I know I can get the parent to be the root in this case, but as I explained in my edit that's not always a safe assumption.  If it seems like I'm being pedantic, the larger context is that I'm working on this for a book; so it's not just a matter of "make it work", but "make it work as correctly as possible".

Comment: I'll also add:  I tried to get the root window inside the `MainMenu` class using `self.winfo_toplevel()`, and interestingly it returns a reference to the menu itself, rather than the rootwindow.  I think my only option to get the root window without making assumptions about the parent is to use `tkinter._get_default_root()`.  Sadly that seems to be designated as a private function, so it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: You're passing the root in as an argument so I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menus are are managed by the OS on OSX and Windows, and tkinter has very little control over their behavior. I doubt sending events to the menu on either of those platforms will work.

I would say that sending events to the menu is an anti-pattern. Unless the events are directly related to the menu, you should be sending the events to either the top-level window associated with the menu, the root window, or the window that has the keyboard focus, depending on what the event represents.

Since you're passing in the parent widget as a positional argument, you can use that to get the toplevel window associated with the menu.

For example:

```
class MainMenu(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        top = parent.winfo_toplevel()
        submenu.add_command(
            label="foo",
            command=lambda: top.event_generate('<<Foo>>')
        )
        ...
```

Comment: The same visibility problem effects all tkinter widgets from my experience. The only thing is that the menu's visibility isn't updated when it is displayed as part of a tkinter window.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I don't know what you're saying. My answer has nothing to do with visibility. In this specific case, if `top` isn't visible, it would be possible to select an item from the menu since it would be invisible too.

Comment: I am talking about your reference to how tkinter doesn't have much control over the menu's behaviour. I am saying that from what I could test all widgets act like that when you don't call `.pack`/`.grid`/`.place` on them.

Comment: Bryan, thanks for the response.  I don't think there is a better answer to *how* to do this, but I am intrigued by the way you phrased your response.  I think my mental model around events is slightly different (possibly wrong?), coming at it from more of a pub-sub or signals & slots model. Your wording seems to suggest that you see `event_generate` as sending events *to* the menu, while I see it as sending events *from* the menu, which is why it makes sense to me to generate events on the menu object.  Is my mental model wrong?

Comment: @AlanMoore: yes, I think your mental model is backwards. Events are sent _to_ widgets. Think of clicking on a button. The physical button causes an event to be generated on the button itself. Binding events to functions says, in effect, "when widget X receives event Y, call function Z".

Comment: It's a bit clearer in plain Tk, where it's more obvious that the window is the target. Tkinter obscures this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, not 100% sure though.

Look at this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def trying_to_reach(event):
    print("!")

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

text.bind("<<Foo>>", trying_to_reach)
root.after(100, text.event_generate, "<<Foo>>")

root.mainloop()
```

100 ms after the code is run, `!` appears on the screen but I comment the `text.pack()`, nothing is displayed on the screen. Also if I change `root.after(100, text.event_generate, "<<Foo>>")` to `text.event_generate("<<Foo>>")`, nothing is displayed on the screen. This proves @BryanOakley's theory that it has something to do with widget's visibility. That means that the problem most likely lies somewhere in `tcl`/ the functions `tcl` calls.

The solution would be to have a dummy widget or as @Matiiss suggested just use `root.event_generate` and `root.bind`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `pack` per se, though it could potentially have to do with whether the widget is actually visible or not. On Windows, menus are native Windows widgets which aren't managed by Tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know that menus are managed by windows (that is why I can't change their background :D). I don't think the problem is with tkinter. I am betting on `tcl` or whatever functions `tcl` calls. Also if I change `root.after(100, text.event_generate, "<<Foo>>")` to `text.event_generate("<<Foo>>")`, it doesn't work. That proves your visibility theory.

Comment: You are correct that the problem isn't with tkinter. The problem is how tcl/tk implements its menus on Windows.